# Simple_form default method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, routes, simple-form

This is a very simple question but i cannot find anything in the documentation that confirms that the default method for simple_form is POST or GET?

Also, does simple form make use of route helpers so when you click the submit button what it's actually doing is calling a route helper in order to compute a URL?

Can anyone clarify or give me the right doc that confirms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple form is just a wrapper around the `form_for` helper. in this regard it behaves just like it by using `POST` as a default for forms and resolving the path using the path-helpers depending on what you pass to `simple_from_for`.